# How does sapply work in the example below?

Tags: r

```
sapply(list(runif (10), runif (10)), 
       function(x) c(min = min(x), mean = mean(x), max = max(x)))
```

Why is the above code giving a matrix of 3 rows and 2 columns and not 2 rows and 3 columns ?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**(original answer with explanation below)**:**

We can use `ldply` from `plyr` as it directly gives us a `data.frame` object.

```
plyr::ldply(list(runif(10),runif(10)),
            function(x) c(Min=min(x),Mean=mean(x),Max=max(x)))


  #         Min      Mean       Max #No seed
   # 1 0.03964594 0.3960042 0.7345305
   # 2 0.05233872 0.3811633 0.9713190
```

**Original:**

It makes a list with two components:

```
list(runif(10),runif(10))
```

From each list, we find the minimum,maximum and mean hence the output.
To understand why, try running this alone:

```
sapply(list(runif (10)), function(x) c(min = min(x), mean = mean(x), max = max(x)))
```

If you change the `simplify` argument, you can get the output you wish(I assume) to have:

```
sapply(list(runif (10)), function(x) c(min = min(x), mean = mean(x), max = max(x)),
       simplify = F)

 #[[1]]
 #         min      mean       max #No seed
 #  0.2482040   0.4845170 0.8294896
```

**NOTE::** You need to `set.seed` for reproducibility.